# 303 error using the remote method of jquery validation

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, jquery-validate, codeigniter-3

I am using CodeIgniter, I have one field which is called as `change_password_id`. The user can enter the id and it will check the id exist or not in the database using the remote method of Jquery validation.

I am getting the `303 error` in the network tab.

The controller is not calling from AJAX.

[image]

```
$(function() {
  $("#reset_password_request").validate({
    rules: {
      change_password_id: {
        required: true,
        remote: {
          url: "<?php echo base_url()?>Employee_control/checkemp_exist",
          type: "post",
          data: {
            change_password_id: function() {
              return $("#change_password_id").val();
            }
          }
        }
      },
    },
    messages: {
      change_password_id: {
        remote: "This emp Id is not registered with us."
      }
    },

    submitHandler: function(form) {
      // console.log(form.submit)

      form.submit();
    }

  });
});
```

**Controller**

```
public function checkemp_exist(){
   echo $correct_emp_id= $this->input->post('change_password_id');
   /*I will add code here after some time*/
   }
```

**form**

```
<?php echo form_open('','id="reset_password_request"'); ?>
<div class="form_group">
  <input type="text" class="form_control" id="change_password_id" name="change_password_id">
  <?php echo form_error('change_password_id'); ?>
</div>
<div class="btn_container">
  <button class="btn_default orange_bg" type="submit"> Send request </button>
</div>
<?php echo form_close(); ?>
```

Comment: The response from the server must be JSON encoded text, not a boolean.

Comment: @Sparky, First thing is it's not calling my controller.

Comment: Was not claiming my comment would solve the posted problem or I would have posted it as an answer below, but if you don't echo a JSON encoded string it won't matter anyway.

Comment: You also do not need the `data` parameter if all it contains is `change_password_id` -  that's exactly what is being sent by default when you leave out this parameter.

Comment: @Sparky, I tried for email and the Same code is working.

Comment: @Sparky, I commented the data from ajax.

Comment: I have zero experience with _jquery-validate_ and _codeigniter-3_ but i will try first to make a basic controller, like this one: `public function checkemp_exist(){
   echo json_encode(false); }`. And check what errors you receive now.

Comment: Please be careful about what you're telling us versus what you're showing us.  You say the field is called `emp_id`, but your code is only showing a field called `change_password_id`.   The "303" is a server error and not caused by JavaScript.  Are you using CodeIgniter's built-in CSRF protection?

Comment: Did you inspect your DOM to see what your PHP is rendering for the `URL` parameter?